# Convergence of Quasi-Newton method with fixed derivative

Tags: na.numerical-analysis, nonlinear-optimization

Consider the Newton iteration

$x^{(k+1)} = x^{(k)} - DF( x^{(k)} )^{-1} \cdot F( x^{(k)} )$

to find a zero of a function $F : \mathbb R^k \rightarrow \mathbb R^k$. If we freeze the first derivative, we get the quasi-Newton method

$x^{(k+1)} = x^{(k)} - DF( x^{(1)} )^{-1} \cdot F( x^{(k)} )$

This way, we do not need to invert a matrix at every step, at the cost of possibly worse convergence.

**Question:** What is known about the convergence of the second iteration? This trick seems to be quite common in practical computations, but I have had a hard time finding any discussion of its convergence. Even a non-optimal estimate would interest me.

Comment: You should be able to get a feel for it by "looking at the standard picture" and tweaking it. For example, try to find the root of y=exp(x) starting at x=0. (Good luck!) You take much smaller steps toward a "zero" with the quasi version.  You can imagine a plethora of failures of the quasi method this way. For many practical cases, I imagine the behaviour will be similar to the above failure.  Gerhard "Maybe Evaluate The Derivative Periodically?" Paseman, 2020.01.30.

Comment: That's how the inverse function theorem is proved in most textbooks. It is just the Picard iteration for a contractive mapping given by the RHS which converges only as a geometric progression, so if you need really high precision and really fast, the trick is a bad idea unless you take a few standard Newton iterations first to get the contracting coefficient very close to $0$. Not sure if there is anything else to say about it.

Comment: I have restated the question to illustrate the motivation in a better way.